# 2013 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

As we now have multiple running candidates for the moderator election, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I will be working with candidates to determine a time for the event.

***The Town Hall Chat took place Thurdsay the 21st at 15:00:00Z UTC. A digest is available [here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/2013-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).***

Here are the details so far:

- I will be scheduling this some time near the beginning of the election phase. Because of the timing of enough candidates to run an election, I'm looking at somewhere in between Tuesday and Thursday this week (19th-21st). As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=cooking.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation. *If you cannot attend but have a concerned question you'd like to pose, feel free to post it as a response here and I will ask on your behalf*.
- Priority for scheduling is generally towards the greatest number of candidate openings as well as the earliest. Candidates who cannot show up during the live event will still be able to answer all questions posted, they will just do so at their earliest convenience.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: I will be at work during the chat.  I think the questions I would like to have answered are: Why do you feel we need any additional moderators at this time, given the low activity level on SA?  What contribution will you add as a moderator that is different from our current moderators?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I'm not sure if you should post your questions as a comment or as a response. Nevertheless, I'll try to make sure your questions will be asked.